# Postgres is doing a sequential scan when an index scan in simplest possible query

Tags: postgresql

Variants of this question have been asked multiple times before but in my case the query is the simplest query one could possibly do: `select * from table_name where id = ?`. Here's all the steps I took:

```sql
create extension "uuid-ossp";
create table test (id uuid primary key default uuid_generate_v4());
insert into test select from generate_series(1, 1000000);
explain analyze select * from test where id = uuid_generate_v4();
```

Here's the output:

```sql
CREATE EXTENSION
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 1000000
                                                      QUERY PLAN                                                      
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Gather  (cost=1000.00..12656.79 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=593.754..596.870 rows=0 loops=1)
   Workers Planned: 2
   Workers Launched: 2
   ->  Parallel Seq Scan on test  (cost=0.00..11656.69 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=572.223..572.223 rows=0 loops=3)
         Filter: (id = uuid_generate_v4())
         Rows Removed by Filter: 333333
 Planning Time: 0.113 ms
 Execution Time: 596.887 ms
(8 rows)
```

This makes absolutely no sense to me. Why wouldn't Postgres opt to do an index scan here?

I'm using the latest version of Postgres, v13.3.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your own answer is correct, but doesn't really explain why.
The explanation is that uuid_generate_v4() is a volatile function.  The way PostgreSQL implements that, it is executing it one time for each row in the table, and compares the result--a different one each time--to the stored value for that row.

You can trick PostgreSQL by putting it into a subquery, as PostgreSQL doesn't track the volatility of subqueries.

```
explain analyze select * from test where id = (select uuid_generate_v4());
```

Now uuid_generate_v4() is called only once, and it will use the index.

Answer (score 2):

My mistake was to use `uuid_generate_v4()` in the `where` clause instead of a single UUID. Using a UUID value like `'51e7c7e5-63a5-46ea-a698-9066b869d208'` does result in an index scan.